# Java Regex meaning of {1,}

Tags: java

Consider following code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "xxzz";
        String str2 = "xyz";
        String str3 = "yzz";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(xx)*y?z{1,}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str1);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher(str2).matches());
        System.out.println(
        Pattern.compile("(xx)*y?z{1,}").
        matcher(str3).matches());
    }
}
```

This code produces output as follows:

```
true
false
true
```

But if I remove `{1,}` then it will produces output as follows:

```
false
false
false
```

I am not able to understand use of `{1,}` and how it works please provide suggestion and help for same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This clause is known as a quantifier.

---

It indicates a specific number, lists of numbers, or range (to infinity). A number indicates an exact number of occurrences. The coma is used to indicate multiple (when between numbers) or a range to infinity (when not followed by a number.

This later is this case: The clause will check for 1 or more occurrences of the previous group.

However, you can replace `{1,}` with  `+` in the same place to do the same effect with less characters.

I use [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com) as a resource for learning and exploring regex, it's wonderful. Also, here is a very thorough [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) which covers regex accross different versions, and here is the [Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) about quantifiers specifically.

Comment: @SarangShinde I just added some more links which I have just found. You may find the Oracle link especially useful :)

Comment: Thanks you for providing such valuable links